# Why can't I name my SailsJS models the same as my MySQL tables?

Tags: javascript, mysql, model-view-controller, express, sails.js

I'm just getting started with Sails JS and I'm inexperienced with RESTful API's. To get things started I generated a `User` model as the guide suggests. I figured this would match to my `users` table. I added attributes to my model based on my tables columns. When I lifted my server and made a GET request on my users, it returned all of my users! I figured I was okay to generate the rest of my models at this point, so I created several more. That's when I ran into problems. I started getting this error: `ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELEC FROM 'timeline' AS "timeline"' at line 1`. This threw me off. Based on the syntax error, I thought maybe it was something I could have done, though I hadn't written any queries anywhere. I then noticed that when I changed my model name from "Timeline" to "Timelines", I didn't have a problem.

It seems to me, Sails has a problem with me naming my models the same name as my tables. Why is this? Wouldn't doing so be more logical? Furthermore, is Sails attempting to automatically match my models to my tables?

Comment: Yes, it's odd. This was the only example of something similar that I was able to find on the web: https://github.com/LogBlock/LogBlock/issues/142

Answer (score 0):

No. Sails.js names tables exactly as models (with lowercase first letter). You probably have error somewhere else or you application crashes before sails engine regenerate database tables.

To check this out install clean sails instance, save `models.migrate` equal to `alter` in your configuration, and generate any API that you want with `sails generate api apiName`. Lift sails and you'll see that `apiName` table is present in your database and `ApiName.js` model.

This behavior can produce troubles while working with old legacy databases or when model name does not represent data it will store. In this case you can set `tableName` property in your model to be equal the name of your table ([documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/model-settings.html?q=tablename)).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by connecting my SQL table like this and simply gave my rows columnName attribute

```
api/models/User.js
module.exports = {
  connection: 'shinyNewMySQLDatabase',
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      columnName: 'MY_SQL_COLUMN_NAME'
    },
    password: {
      type: 'string',
      columnName: 'MY_SQL_COLUMN_PASSWORD'
    },
    email: {
      type: 'email',
      unique: true,
      columnName: 'MY_SQL_COLUMN_EMAIL'
    }
  }
};
```

Check the documentation bellow
http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes
If it was helpful, let me know

Answer (score 0):

provide table name at the place of 'connection' as tableName: 'My_Table_Name' and give connection in config/connections.js file as
sqlServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-sqlserver',
    user: 'UserName',
    password: 'YourPassword',
    database: 'DatabaseName'
  },

and give this connection to the config/models.js as 
connection: 'sqlServer'

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can take same Model name as Table name by using ORM but in this you doesn't need to define tableName in model. In ORM it will automatically match model name and table name.